# Get rid of the DrillDown in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, coffeescript

I got a line chart and i want to disable or hide the drill down. I read the documentation and I i haven't found it
Any suggestions?
Thanx!

Comment: What do you mean by "drill down"? Do you mean tooltip? If so, `tooltip: false` will do the trick.

Comment: Drill down is not default behavior - you have to specifically set drill down up in your data structure, and by including an extra js file. So if you don;w want drill down, simply don't include it. If you do mean tooltip, the properties are all here that explain how to do it:http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.enabled